# Auto Scrolling in LWUIT Container

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-container

I have a not scrollable `Form` with a `BorderLayout`. In the `CENTER` of this `BorderLayout`, I have made a scrollable `Container` with `BoxLayoutY`. Inside this `Container` are appearing more `Container`. When there are a lot of `Containers` the `CENTER` `Container` is scrollable, but the last element is nos visible, I have to go down with the focus to see the last `Container`. What I want to do is:
When a new `Container` appears in the `CENTER` `Container` , this `Container` must scroll down, revealing the last `Container` added...is like an auto-scrolling.
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about :

```
componentOfLastContainer.requestFocus();
centerBigContainer.repaint();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try this!